# lidR canopy height map has holes/jagged edges

Tags: lidr

I am trying to create a canopy height map from LIDAR point cloud data (LAS format) but I get some jagged edges/holes in my results (see photo). Is there a parameter I can tweak to fill these in? I tried adding the subcircle parameter to pitfree but still have the holes/edges. Here is the code I am using:

```
        library(lidR)
        library(terra)
        library(sf)
        print("Calculating CHM")
        las = readLAS(input)
        nonnoise <- filter_poi(las, Classification != 18) # remove high noise
        nlas <- normalize_height(nonnoise, knnidw())
        chm <- rasterize_canopy(nlas, res = 1, algorithm = pitfree(subcircle = 0.15), pkg = "terra")
        writeRaster(chm, sprintf('./out/%s_chm.tif', filename), overwrite=TRUE)
```

[image: chm]

[image: chm2]

Edit: I tweaked my code to the following to fix this issue:

```
chm <- rasterize_canopy(nlas, res = 1, algorithm = pitfree(max_edge = c(3, 3), subcircle = 1.4))
fill.na <- function(x, i=5) { if (is.na(x)[i]) { return(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) } else { return(x[i]) }}
w <- matrix(9,9,9)
filled <- terra::focal(chm, w, fun = fill.na)
smoothed <- terra::focal(filled, w = matrix(1,3,3), fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is the problem? I'm not even sur of what I'm seeing. I see some urban image under green vegetation that looks nice.

Comment: @JRR Thank you for the reply. I edited my question to include a second photo of my CHM in grayscale with some more examples of the holes I get in my resulting CHM. I am wondering about methods I can try to remove the holes, or to avoid creating them in the first place

Comment: Ok I see, you are running a triangulation-based algorithm for CHM you should have a continuous CHM without any gaps. Yet you have gaps in... gaps. This is not expected indeed. Please share data so we can reproduce.

Comment: @JRR Thank you. Here is a link to the raw .las file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rYDgvrmrqqxy9VcYn31mMHahPw_tBmvR/view?usp=sharing and accompanying documentation https://lariac-lacounty.hub.arcgis.com/pages/lariac4-documents-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following. Everything look good except the geometric deformation due to steep slopes. Please provide a reproducible example.

```r
library(lidR)
library(terra)
library(sf)

ctg = readLAScatalog("L4_6577_1894.las",  select = "xyzrc", filter = "-drop_class 18")
las = clip_rectangle(ctg, 6579000,1897000, 6579000+1000,1897000+1000)
nlas <- normalize_height(las, knnidw())
chm <- rasterize_canopy(nlas, res = 1, algorithm = pitfree(subcircle = 0.15))
plot(chm, col = height.colors(25))
```

Comment: Thank you, I ran this code in RStudio, saved the raster to tif `writeRaster(chm, 'chmtest.tif')`, and then opened in QGIS, zoomed in and am seeing this for example in the bottom left corner: https://imgur.com/a/18sXgtn, does that match what you are seeing? By the way, I am using sf_1.0-14    terra_1.7-55 lidR_4.0.4  with R version 4.3.2

Comment: The pit free algorithm is design to avoid pits. You have pits, which means that you must tune some parameters I guess. To be able to tune the parameters, you must understand the algorithm. To understand the algorithm, you must read the publication that is associated with it. I myself need to read it again and make some trial and error. By the way, I also wrote an illustrated demonstration of the algorithm here https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/chm.html#pitfree

Comment: thanks I'll play around some more and report results if I get any success!

Comment: I played around with the pitfree settings and decided these look best for my data: `pitfree(max_edge = c(3, 3), subcircle = 1.4)` and combined with the fill and smoothing steps from chapter 6.4 of your book I am now getting good looking output: https://imgur.com/a/sBjRYcw I updated my question with my working code.